# Adding side effect to evaluating an existing cell

Tags: front-end, evaluation

When I develop a package I typically open a new notebook and start
writing functions which I need until I have a version which I am happy
with. Then I copy them to a m-file. During this process I usually go
back to an existing cell and change few things and hit SHIFT+RETURN to
see the effect of changes. The problem is that as the this happens
during several sessions, when I go through the cells in a notebook,
the order of the cells does not necessarily represent the order in
which I have carried out the calculations.

I was wondering if it is possible to have a shortcut such that every
time I want to reevaluate an existing cell, it gets copied to the end
of notebook. Preferably the shortcut should have two version such that
one just copies the cell to the end of notebook (just in case I want
to make some changes before evaluating it) and the other copies the
cell to the end of notebook and evaluates it without any changes. Of
course I can do this manually for each cell but it would be nice to
have a less time consuming way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding a cell at the bottom of the [`InputNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputNotebook) after every evaluation, the following function takes the input and output cells for a given range of line numbers, and writes them in evaluation order in a new [`Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook):

```
Options[evaluationSequenceNB]={"IncludeOutput"->True};

evaluationSequenceNB[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := evaluationSequenceNB[1;;$Line, opts]
 evaluationSequenceNB[s_Span, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := evaluationSequenceNB[Range[$Line][[s]], opts]
evaluationSequenceNB[rng_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{cells},
    cells = toInCell[InString[rng], rng];
    If[TrueQ@OptionValue["IncludeOutput"],
        cells=Riffle[
            cells,
            Replace[
                DownValues[Out][[rng]],
                _[_[_[line_]], z_] :>toOutCell[MakeBoxes[z], line],
                {1}
            ]
        ]
    ];
    NotebookPut[Notebook[cells]]
]

SetAttributes[toInCell, Listable];
toInCell[boxString_, line_] := Cell[
    ToExpression[boxString, StandardForm, BoxData],
    "Input",
    CellLabel->"In["<>ToString[line]<>"]:="
]

toOutCell[boxes_, line_] := Block[{$Line=line},
    Cell[
        BoxData @ ToBoxes @ OutputSizeLimit`PrePrint[RawBoxes@boxes],
        "Output",
        CellLabel->"Out["<>ToString[line]<>"]="
    ]
]
```

For example, here is an image of a notebook after evaluating 3 inputs, where the order is reversed (as you can see by the [`In`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/In)/[`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out) numbers):

[image]

And, here is the notebook generated by `evaluationSequenceNB`:

[image]